# Pygame : Is color readable from a class variable in function pygame.draw.rect?

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to know if is possible to use the `pygame.draw.rect()` function in pygame with a color variable in a class.

This is my code with details works explications under it :
( note that I've take only the useful part )

```py
# consider pygame as 'pg' as I set with
# the line 'import pygame as pg'

class icon:
    def __init__(self, picture, position, key):
        self.icon = picture
        self.position = position
        self.p_x, self.p_y = position
        self.size = 50
        self.unlocked = False
        self.key = key
        self.status = 'off'
        self.pulse_value = 0
        self.pulse = 'down'
        self.pulse_type = 'red'
        self.c_icon = self.icon.get_rect()
        self.c_icon.center = ( (self.p_x + 25), (self.p_y + 25))

    def unlock(self):
        self.unlocked = True
        self.status = 'pulse'
        self.pulse_type = 'grey'

    def draw(self):
        if self.unlocked == True :
            if self.status == 'off':
                pg.draw.rect(screen, color_passive, (*self.position, 50, 48))

            elif self.status == 'on':
                pg.draw.rect(screen, color_active, (*self.position, 50, 55))

            elif self.status == 'pulse':
                if self.pulse == 'down' :
                    self.pulse_value = self.pulse_value + 1
                    if self.pulse_value == 255 :
                        self.pulse = 'up'

                elif self.pulse == 'up' :
                    self.pulse_value = self.pulse_value - 1
                    if self.pulse == 0 :
                        self.pulse = 'down'

                if self.pulse_type == 'red' :
                    self.color_pulse = (self.pulse_value, 0, 0)
                elif self.pulse_type == 'grey' :
                    self.color_pulse = (self.pulse_value, self.pulse_value, self.pulse_value )
                pg.draw.rect(screen, *self.color_pulse, (*self.position, *self.size))

            screen.blit(self.icon, self.c_icon)

world_2 = pg.image.load('ice_mountains.png').convert_alpha()
icon_1 = icon('world_2', (60, 60), K_1)
```

This is the class icon, that shpw any tabs icons on screen and define if the tab is unlock or not.

As you can see, I use here a function `pygame.draw.rect()`

But in this function, The color variable is a 'class variable' `( self.color_pulse)`.

The variable `self.color_pulse` is define by `(  self.pulse_value, self.pulse_value, self.pulse_value)` on the line above.

And `self.pulse_value` is a class variable that Increases by 5 each `icon_2.draw()` at speed 30 times per seconds.

Basicly, I use the function `icon_2.draw()` in the main loop.

```py
    elif exp >= 1000:
        n_unlock = n_unlock + 1
        icon_2.unlock()
        print('world 2 unlocked')
```

this is the code for unlock the icon. At the point when the main loop execute the `icon_2.draw()` just after this one is unlocked, the result expected is that the icon should be appear at the screen,defaul..ulse until user click on it.

BUT, unfortunately, I got this :

```
#----------*={ _MAD_ }=*----------#
        May Avoid Destruction         
             by Edhyjox           
#----------*={ _MAD_ }=*----------#

Loading...
========== Ok

custom setting succesfully imported
Window main not existing, redirect to game

World 2 unlocked
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "************************/___MAD___/script/MAD - The game.py", line 266, in <module>
    icon_2.draw()
  File "************************/___MAD___/script/MAD - The game.py", line 190, in draw
    pg.draw.rect(screen, *self.color_pulse, (*self.position, *self.size))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I don't really why I got this error. This mean that I use 'int' in the function `pg.draw.rect()`, but the variable self.color_pulse is (5, 5, 5) at this point of the program.

And It seems to work for variable that not in a class...
Is here anyone have a clue on the problem ?

Comment: Sorry for languge mistakes, I try to improve :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) has to be a color. In PyGame a color can be a tuple of 3 integral values.
So the  `*`-operator (unpack operator) is superfluous.

Note that

> ```
> self.color_pulse = (self.pulse_value, 0, 0)
> pg.draw.rect(screen, *self.color_pulse, (*self.position, *self.size))
> ```

is the same as

```py
pg.draw.rect(screen, self.color_pulse, 0, 0, (*self.position, *self.size))
```

Consider the that `self.pulse_value` is initialized by `0` in the constructor.

> ```
> self.pulse_value = 0
> ```

If `self.pulse_type` is neither `'red'` nor `'grey'`, then `*self.color_pulse` won't work anyway and cause an error.

---

Further the 3rd parameter has to be a rectangle. A rectangle is a tuple of 4 values, but `self.size` is single integral value.

> ```
> self.size = 50
> ```

So `*self.size` leads to an error.

---

Skip the `*`-operator before `self.color_puls` and change `*self.size` to `self.size, self.size`:

```py
pg.draw.rect(screen, self.color_pulse, (*self.position, self.size, self.size))
```

Comment: Wihout the * operator, I got the same result `line 190, in draw
    pg.draw.rect(screen, self.color_pulse, (*self.position, *self.size))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Edhyjox Oh, I see. I change the answer. It has to be `(*self.position, self.size, self.size)`

Comment: Oh, thank, I tought it was color cause it begun to not work when I edit it but I didn't look at all others parameters ! Thank you, now lets did it with all the others tab ._.

Comment: Yeah, As I espect, the tab with the icon appear when I giving myself the require xp, ans the rectangle behind the picture glowing !

Comment: Is it useful to rewrite a full awnser or I can just approvate the one above ?

Comment: Just if I approuvate a awnser, It will give you more privilegdes points and reach 50k gold :)

Comment: Yes don't worry